# pyspark - creating Row instance inside createDataFrame() method

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

Following code is supposed to create a dataframe `df2` with two columns - first column storing the name of each column of `df` and the second column storing the max length of each column of `df`. But I'm getting the error shown below:

**Question**: What I may be doing wrong here, and how can we fix the error?

> NameError: name 'row' is not defined

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, length, max
from pyspark.sql import Row

df = df.select([max(length(col(name))).alias(name) for name in df.schema.names])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([Row(col=name, length=row[name]) for name in df.schema.names], ['col', 'length'])
```

Comment: Hi Nam, apologies for the error - there was a missing line, I've added in the original answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies Nam, Please find the below-working snippet. There was a line missing in the original answer, I've updated the same.

```
df = df.select([max(length(col(name))).alias(name) for name in df.schema.names])
row=df.first().asDict()
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([Row(col=name, length=row[name]) for name in df.schema.names], ['col', 'length'])
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Let me know if you face any other issue